# How to extract value of an element based on its sibling element in a parent node using xpath or xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a payload which like this,

```
<Payload> 
  <Identifier> 
    <Type>typeA</Type>  
    <Value>valueOfA</Value> 
  </Identifier>  
  <Identifier> 
    <Type>typeB</Type>  
    <Value>valueOfB</Value> 
  </Identifier> 
</Payload>
```

I want to extract the value of element 'typeA' using xpath or xquery to proceed further so that my transformed payload looks like this

```
<transformedPayload>
<typeA>valueOfA</typeA>
<typeB><valueOfB</typeB>
</transformedPayload>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easily done in XQuery. The following query does what you want:

```
<transformedPayload>{
  for $ident in /Payload/Identifier
  return element { $ident/Type } { $ident/Value/text() }
}</transformedPayload>
```

If you want to select only a subset of all `Identifier`s, you can use the `where` clause:

```
<transformedPayload>{
  for $ident in /Payload/Identifier
  where $ident/Type eq 'typeA'
     or $ident/Type eq 'typeB'
  return element { $ident/Type } { $ident/Value/text() }
}</transformedPayload>
```

You can also use the `=` operator and its *existantial semantics* to make this more compact:

```
<transformedPayload>{
  for $ident in /Payload/Identifier
  where $ident/Type = ('typeA', 'typeB')
  return element { $ident/Type } { $ident/Value/text() }
}</transformedPayload>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I have one more doubt. Let's say there are N number of elements out there like <Payload> 
  <Identifier> 
    <Type>typeA</Type>  
    <Value>valueOfA</Value> 
  </Identifier>  
  <Identifier> 
    <Type>typeB</Type>  
    <Value>valueOfB</Value> 
  </Identifier> 

 <Identifier> 
    <Type>typeC</Type>  
    <Value>valueOfC</Value> 
  </Identifier> 
</Payload>
But I have to extract only typeA and typeB, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you please look at the above comment?

Comment: I have added examples for that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)